# Automate repetitive file and folder creation npm

Tags: npm

I am experimenting with methods to create reusable components for use in front end html/scss projects. Supposing all components would have the same folder and file structure, I was hoping if it is possible to automate this task.

I am new to the workflow and jargon in modern web design and I have just recently started off with npm (currently using node-sass and browser sync).
I was hoping if someone could recommend the simplest way to automate the repetitive creation of files and folders. Perhaps regarding if any npm packages might exist for this purpose (i have tried npm folder-template, but have reason to believe it does not work properly on windows machines).

I would appreciate if someone could explain the terminology used for such a task, as I have come across terms such as scaffolding, templates, Yeoman and npm generate, and I am confused about how I should proceed.

An example structure:

```
featured-content/
|     break-points/
|     |_base.scss  
|     |_xl.scss  
|     |_l.scss 
|     |_m.scss  
|     |_s.scss 
|     |_xs.scss
|
|_featured-content.scss
```

[image]

Many thanks for your time and help,
Sam

Answer (score 1):

An npm package by the name of 'plop' is exactly what i was looking for to generate files and folders based on a pattern. 'plop' is a generator framework which makes generating files simpler and less repetitive and supports user prompts and handlebar templates.

**Links to package and documentation**

https://plopjs.com/documentation/

https://www.npmjs.com/package/plop

**Implementation of plopfile.js**

```
module.exports = function (plop) {

//prepend selectors to avoid conflicts
var companyName = 'super';
var themeName = 'awesome';

// prefix combine
var prefix = companyName + '-' + themeName + '-';

//paths
var blockPath = 'includes/blocks/components/';
var sectionPath = 'includes/sections/components/';
var blockModifyPath = 'includes/blocks/_blocks.scss';
var sectionModifyPath = 'includes/sections/_sections.scss';

plop.setHelper('prefix', function () {
    return prefix;
});

// block generator
plop.setGenerator('block', {
    description: 'generate block',
    prompts: [{
        type: 'input',
        name: 'name',
        message: 'block name please'
    }],
    actions: [
        //import file
        {
            type: 'add',
            path: blockPath + '{{name}}/_{{name}}.scss',
            templateFile: 'plop-templates/blocks/blocks.hbs'
        },
        //php file
        {
            type: 'add',
            path: blockPath + '{{name}}/{{name}}.php',
            templateFile: 'plop-templates/blocks/php.hbs'
        },
        //breakpoint base size
        {
            type: 'add',
            path: blockPath + '{{name}}/break-points/_base.scss',
            templateFile: 'plop-templates/blocks/base.hbs'

        },
        //breakpoint xl size
        {
            type: 'add',
            path: blockPath + '{{name}}/break-points/_xl.scss',
            templateFile: 'plop-templates/blocks/xl.hbs'
        },
        //breakpoint l size
        {
            type: 'add',
            path: blockPath + '{{name}}/break-points/_l.scss',
            templateFile: 'plop-templates/blocks/l.hbs'
        },
        //breakpoint m size
        {
            type: 'add',
            path: blockPath + '{{name}}/break-points/_m.scss',
            templateFile: 'plop-templates/blocks/m.hbs'
        },
        //breakpoint s size
        {
            type: 'add',
            path: blockPath + '{{name}}/break-points/_s.scss',
            templateFile: 'plop-templates/blocks/s.hbs'
        },
        //breakpoint xs size
        {
            type: 'add',
            path: blockPath + '{{name}}/break-points/_xs.scss',
            templateFile: 'plop-templates/blocks/xs.hbs'
        },
            //modify blocks file
            {
                type: 'modify',
                path: blockModifyPath,
                pattern: /(\/\/-- IMPORT BLOCKS --)/gi,
                template: '$1\r\n@import "components/{{name}}/{{name}}";'
            }
        ]
    });
    //section generator
    plop.setGenerator('section', {
        description: 'generate section',
        prompts: [{
            type: 'input',
            name: 'name',
            message: 'section name please'
        }],
        actions: [
            //import file
            {
                type: 'add',
                path: sectionPath + '{{name}}/_{{name}}.scss',
                templateFile: 'plop-templates/sections/sections.hbs'
            },
            //php file
            {
                type: 'add',
                path: sectionPath + '{{name}}/{{name}}.php',
                templateFile: 'plop-templates/sections/php.hbs'
            },
            //breakpoint base size
            {
                type: 'add',
                path: sectionPath + '{{name}}/break-points/_base.scss',
                templateFile: 'plop-templates/sections/base.hbs'

            },
            //breakpoint xl size
            {
                type: 'add',
                path: sectionPath + '{{name}}/break-points/_xl.scss',
                templateFile: 'plop-templates/sections/xl.hbs'
            },
            //breakpoint l size
            {
                type: 'add',
                path: sectionPath + '{{name}}/break-points/_l.scss',
                templateFile: 'plop-templates/sections/l.hbs'
            },
            //breakpoint m size
            {
                type: 'add',
                path: sectionPath + '{{name}}/break-points/_m.scss',
                templateFile: 'plop-templates/sections/m.hbs'
            },
            //breakpoint s size
            {
                type: 'add',
                path: sectionPath + '{{name}}/break-points/_s.scss',
                templateFile: 'plop-templates/sections/s.hbs'
            },
            //breakpoint xs size
            {
                type: 'add',
                path: sectionPath + '{{name}}/break-points/_xs.scss',
                templateFile: 'plop-templates/sections/xs.hbs'
            },
            //modify sections file
            {
                type: 'modify',
                path: sectionModifyPath,
                pattern: /(\/\/-- IMPORT SECTIONS --)/gi,
                template: '$1\r\n@import "components/{{name}}/{{name}}";'
            }
        ]
    });
};
```